# Eclipse RCP: boolean variable to check a View active or not

Tags: java, eclipse, view, eclipse-rcp

I want to have a Boolean variable that is true if a view has already been activated in the RCP GUI, otherwise false.

I tried the following code:

```
        IViewPart view = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("view.id");

        if (view != null){
            System.out.println("View Active");
        }
```

But it returns a view even though it has not been activated in the GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

findView should return null if view has not been created at all. If by 'active' you mean brought up to front/visible currently, try using IWorkbenchPage.isPartVisible

Answer (score 1):

Try finding a view reference, without trying to restore the view, like this:

```
IViewReference viewReference = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findViewReference("view.id");

if (viewReference.getView(false) != null) {
    System.out.println("View Active");
}
```